# How to apply a function to all strings in record's structure recursively using jq

Tags: json, recursion, jq

Is it possible to apply a recursive transformation to a record to return the same record, but having all `string` values mapped?

For example:

```
{"x":"1", "a": {"b": 2, "c": ["a"]}, "d": {"e": "z"}}
```

with a mapping of "add prime" applied:

```
{"x":"1'", "a": {"b": 2, "c": ["a'"]}, "d": {"e": "z'"}}
```

I've tried using a combination of `recurse`, `map`, `string` and `select` with little luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this easily with the recurse operator:

`jq '(.. | strings) += "\'"'`

Where `..` generates a stream by recursively iterating through every element of the input, `strings` filters the stream for those who are strings, `+=` adds the right-hand element to every element on the left-hand stream and `"\'"` is a literal containing the "prime" you seek.

Comment: Is there a way get access to the current value on right hand side? Say if I wanted to do something more complex like `jq '(.. | strings) = f(value)`, could that be done?

Comment: Sure! There's the `|=` operator for that: `jq '(.. | strings) |= f'`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `walk/1`.  It is explained in the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

If your jq does not have it defined, here is its definition from [builtin.jq](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq):

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
```

Comment: Very cool, just came to this conclusion independently. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **paths/1** to identify string values and updates them with **reduce**, **setpath** and **getpath**

```
reduce paths(type == "string") as $p (
    .
  ; setpath($p; getpath($p) + "'")
)
```